# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForProdRelease'

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-r8

I'm migrating my flutter app to android 13 "API Level 33" but the build failed with this exception `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForPro`
with API level 32 everything works fine but google play announced to expand API level to be 33
my app/build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 33

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my ID"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}`
```

and the gradle.properties
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M android.enableR8=true android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true`

so how to solve this issue?